# How to display information about my app when I use location and background execution

Tags: swift

I use location collection, I want to achieve the effect of the following images, when the collection location is executed and executed in the background, you can display your own app in the status column.

[image]

I thought that as soon as I used the location and background, he would automatically display it. But not as I thought.

The following is my code

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate{

        var locationMgr : CLLocationManager!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            locationMgr = CLLocationManager()
            locationMgr.delegate = self
            locationMgr.desiredAccuracy =         kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationMgr.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            locationMgr.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways {
                locationMgr.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }else{
                locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
            }

        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,    didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            if let a = locations.last{
                print("----location update----")
                print(a.coordinate.latitude);
                print(a.coordinate.longitude);
                print("---------------")
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get the updated data when I execute it, but I don't see the display of the status bar above.

I don't know what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The alert on the top shows when you app has permission to access the location when it is in foreground and uses when the app is in background.

Use

```
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse {
        locationMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }else{
        locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

instead of

```
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways {
        locationMgr.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }else{
        locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Comment: I try to use requestAlwaysAuthorization but still not show....
But thanks for answer.

Comment: @謝佳哲JackHsieh Uninstall the app and try again